# Trouble scooping out a certain portion of text out of a chunk

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I get the address appeared before `Telephone` from the portion of text I've pasted below. I tried with the following but it gives me nothing.

This is the code I've tried so far with:

```
import re

content="""
Campbell, Bellam Associés Inc.

3003 Rue College
 Sherbrooke, QC J1M 1T8 
Telephone: 819-569-9255 
 Website: http://www.assurancescb.com 
"""
pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)(?=Telephone)")
for item in pattern.finditer(content):
    print(item.group())
```

Expected output:

```
Campbell, Bellam Associés Inc.
3003 Rue College
Sherbrooke, QC J1M 1T8
```

The block of texts are always like the pasted one and there is no flag attached to it using which I opt for positive lookbehind so I tried like above instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) does not match a line break character so you could use a [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?s)` or use [re.S](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) or [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)(?=Telephone)", re.S)
```

or

`pattern = re.compile(r"(?s)(.*)(?=Telephone)")`

You could also get the match without using a group:

`(?s).*(?=Telephone)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @The fourth bird for your solution. It wonderfully did the trick.

Comment: I have added a link to [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) that explains about specifying modes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

> pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)(?=Telephone)")

To

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)(?=Telephone)", re.DOTALL)
```

So that your regex wildcard (*) would match newline characters.
:)